# Subtract the Blank row from the other rows but only from specific columns

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a data frame (DF) similar to the one below. I need to remove the Blank values from the  columns Density and Counts.

```
DF <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Date = c("1/1/2000, 1/2/2002,1/2/2002,1/2/2002
  Sample = c("SampleA", "SampleB", "Blank","SampleC"),
  Density = c(30, 20, 10, 50),
  Counts=c(1,2,1,4))
```

This is what I'm expecting

```
Expected <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Date = c("1/1/2000", "1/2/2002","1/2/2002","1/2/2002"),
  Sample = c("SampleA", "SampleB", "Blank","SampleC"),
  Density = c(20, 10, 0, 40),
  Counts=c(0,1,0,3)
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```r
library(tidyverse)

DF %>% mutate(Date=lubridate::mdy(Date)) %>% 
  mutate(new=ifelse(Sample=='Blank',Density, NA),
         new2=ifelse(Sample=='Blank',Counts, NA)) %>% fill(c(new,new2), .direction = 'updown') %>% 
  mutate(Density=ifelse(Sample!='Blank',Density-new, 0),
         Counts=ifelse(Sample!='Blank',Counts-new2, 0)) %>% select(-c(new,new2))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
        Date  Sample Density Counts
1 2000-01-01 SampleA      20      0
2 2002-01-02 SampleB      10      1
3 2002-01-02   Blank       0      0
4 2002-01-02 SampleC      40      3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ifelse`

```
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  "Date" = c("1/1/2000", "1/2/2002","1/2/2002","1/2/2002)",
  "Sample" = c("SampleA", "SampleB", "Blank","SampleC"),
  "Density" = c(30, 20, 10, 50),
  "Counts"=c(1,2,1,4))

DF$Density <- ifelse(DF$Sample == "Blank", 0, DF$Density)
DF$Counts <- ifelse(DF$Sample == "Blank", 0, DF$Counts)
```

or if the "blank is a literal blank

```
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  "Date" = c("1/1/2000", "1/2/2002","1/2/2002","1/2/2002)",
  "Sample" = c("SampleA", "SampleB", "Blank","SampleC"),
  "Density" = c(30, 20, 10, 50),
  "Counts"=c(1,2,1,4))

DF$Density <- ifelse(DF$Sample == "", 0, DF$Density)
DF$Counts <- ifelse(DF$Sample == "", 0, DF$Counts)
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesnt not substract the blank values row from the other values. It just zero the row Blank. See my expected data frame.